# Is there XML, XSLT, and XPATH support in the new Microsoft Edge browser?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath, microsoft-edge

Does anyone have information about XML, XSLT, or XPATH support in the new Microsoft Edge browser?

In specific: When I use the JavaScript function `transformToDocument()`, it ends with the following error message: `“Error in transformNode: Invalid argument”`.

The same code is working with IE 10, IE 11, Chrome, Safari, etc., but unfortunately is not working with the new browser.

Comment: Consider that Microsoft Edge is still a work-in-progress browser that hasn't been fully released yet, so it's entirely possible that these features just haven't been fully implemented yet. However, if you think this is something that is a bug or needs to be implemented, there are myriad ways to let Microsoft know: [Edge Feedback & Support portal](http://dev.modern.ie/community/support/); [Microsoft Edge Suggestion Box](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer); [Microsoft Edge Developer Feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback) feed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get in touch with Microsoft Edge Developers team.

Comment: I spoke with some of them on Twitter this morning, and one of them mentioned XPATH *is* supported in Edge, that there's a fun story behind that, and that he would look into this topic/question more later.

Comment: Thanks, again. I haven't had time to get in touch with Microsoft yet.

Comment: Can you please share a repro, or link to a live demo? I work on the Microsoft Edge team, and would be happy to look into this further for you.

Comment: http://www.adriedenblanken.nl/stamboom/stamboom.htm

Comment: Hi Jonathan, You can take a look at my family tree http://www.adriedenblanken.nl/stamboom/stamboom.htm. This family tree (available in 9 languages) is completely designed with XML (family data) and XSLT to transform the data to HTML. You can take a look at the code behind, e.g. Stamboom.js (JavaScript linking it all together). If you have additional questions, let me know.

Comment: @IamA3 Thank you for the link. I'm happy to look into this with you, but it would greatly help if you could provide reduced cases of the issues affecting your codebase.

Comment: Hi Anthony,

I changed my project and made it a liite bit simpler. Its difficult to make realy small project.

But this is a start: You can find the new project on http://www.adriedenblanken.nl/Stamboom/Edge/FamilyTree.htm

Everything seem to work, only the final step transformToDocument () throws an exception.

FYI: I have zipped the complete project, so you can download it from http://www.adriedenblanken.nl/Stamboom/Edge/FamilyTree.zip.

Of cource not all the links are working anymore, but this is a good start.

If you have further questionslet me know.

Regard,
Adrie

Comment: Hi Anthony, Some extra information. This project works with IE 10, Chrome, Safari en FireFox. I think Chrome is getting close to the implementation in Edge. You can try it your self.
In the file bin\Stamboom.js I have added some alerts (eg alert("Before xp.transformToDocument"). This is the point where the XSLT should start to work.
The first XSLT file is the welcome screen (Voorpagina.xsl). When you klik on a name or on the button "Personal sheet" then the XSLT (Persoonskaart.xsl) is used to transform the XML.

Comment: @JonathanSampson cc'ing you in case OP meant to say your name instead of "Anthony".

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong name! It was of course a message to you (Jonathan)!

Comment: @JonathanSampson, I've posted a question about a possible XPath issue in Edge - I'd appreciate if you get a chance to take a look! I included a minimal reproducable example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787569/xpath-expression-using-and-doesnt-work-in-microsoft-edge

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Edge supports XSLT:

> MSXML6 is the only version of MSXML implemented in Microsoft Edge, which uses it only to implement XSLT [W3C-XSLT].

XPath:

> Microsoft Edge provides [XPATH] functionality natively; see [MS-XPATH] for more information.

and XML (XML DOM, XML Namespaces, XHTML and the responseXML property of the XMLHTTPRequest object).

**References**

- [[MS-ISO8859]: Microsoft Implementations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff520906)
- [[MS-XHTML]: [W3C-XHTML1.0] Section 3.2, User Agent Conformance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934745)
- [[MS-XMLH]: Internet Explorer XML 1.0 (Fifth Edition) Standards Support Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955382)
- [[MS-XPATH]: Microsoft XML XPath Standards Support Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460472(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like XPATH will be included: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn974343(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Related: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6512573-xpath-2-and-3