# XPath expression using "and" doesn't work in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: xml, xpath, microsoft-edge

I'm working on an application that uses XPath expressions to select nodes from XML. We've noticed that this seems to break down for us when testing in the Microsoft Edge preview. I've cut down our code to a brief snippet that demonstrates the issue:

```js
var xml = "<xml id='relationships'><Relationships><f id='some_id' ><f id='some_other_id' /></f></Relationships></xml>";
var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
var nodes = doc.evaluate("//f[@id='some_id' and f]", doc, doc.createNSResolver(doc.documentElement), XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
console.log(nodes.snapshotLength);
```

In Chrome, this will log out `1` and the `nodes.snapshotItem` will contain the correct node, but in Edge, it's logging out `0` and returning no nodes.

If I run either half of this condition separately, `"//f[@id='some_id']"` or `"//f[f]"`, it works consistently across browsers and Edge returns the correct node. It only fails when these two conditions, both true for the node in question, are combined with the `and`. I'm not an XPath expert by any stretch, so can anyone tell me if I'm doing anything nonstandard within this snippet, or if this looks like an issue with the Edge preview's XPath implementation?

Comment: What is the meaning of the `and f`?

Comment: It specifies that we want an `f` element that has at least one `f` child node. It works correctly in all browsers we've tested in, up until Edge.

Comment: Your XPath looks standard to me; MS Edge preview appears to be buggy on this one. You could also try `//f[@id='some_id'][f]` or  `//f[@id='some_id' and count(child::f) > 0]` and see if those fare better in Edge preview.

Comment: I work on the Microsoft Edge team. Our implementation of XPath is largely based on CSS Selectors, and minimally based on Wicked Good XPath. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanSampson! I'll check out the alternate suggestions from LarsH in the meantime, but I appreciate you looking into it!

Comment: It appears as though switching the order to `f and @id='some_id'` resolves the issue. Can you confirm?

Comment: You're correct, it returns the right node when the conditions are flipped around on the "and". Would you agree that the fact that they work in one order but not the other appears to be a bug?

Comment: @sphanley Yes, I would. I am filing this now for our team to review. Thank you for helping bring this to our attention.

Comment: Updating to confirm that this bug is still present in the 10240 build of Windows 10, which means that if it's the RTM build as reported, then this bug will be present in the version of Edge that comes out with the initial release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update: This issue was resolved in the November 2015 update to Windows/Edge*

This appears to be a bug with the *current* implementation in Microsoft Edge. I did notice, however, that if you flip the conditions around, the proper element is retrieved:

```
//f[f and @id='some_id']
```

For the time being, I hope this is an acceptable alternative. I am opening up a bug for our team to review on our end. Than you for helping us improve Microsoft Edge :)

Comment: Any XPath containing: `text()` also does not work also on Microsoft Edge

Comment: @AndrewMarais Would you be able to put together a minimal example for me? I'll gladly file a bug if there's an issue.

Comment: Of course
Event viewer snip from crashed Edge:

**Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll**

URL
(http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_pricenodes_text)

Try view source or try change 'text()=something' and run it

Comment: @AndrewMarais I'm not seeing a crash. Can you create a JSFiddle that crashes when ran, and let me know which version of Windows10/Edge you're testing?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise 64bit, Microsoft Edge 20.10240.16384.0

Comment: This one does not crash Edge, but definitely does not work on Edge: JSFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/v96eszzr/). Use Chrome or another browser to see the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

XPaths that fails in Edge followed by similar alternative:

Fail

```
'/value[Name/text()="Checked"]/Value[text()="true"]'
```

Alternative

```
'/value[Name ="Checked" and Value = "true"]/Value'
```

---

Fail

```
'/value[text()="match1"]'
```

Alternative

```
'/value[.="match1"]'
```

---

Fail

```
'/value[Name[text()="match1"]]'
```

Alternative

```
'/value[Name="match1"]'
```

---

Fail

```
'/value[Name/text()= "match1"]'
```

Alternative

```
'/value[Name= "match1"]'
```

---

Fail

```
'/value[Name[text() = 'match1']]')
```

Alternative

```
'/value[Name = "match1"]')
```